# How to ping hubot deployed on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, hubot, campfire

I have simple hubot app deployed at heroku. I have set the procfile and its running properly when I check the logs using `heroku logs -t`

**coffee script:**

module.exports = (robot) ->

```
   robot.hear /room/i, (res) ->
    res.send "welcome " + res.message.room
```

**procfile:**

```
web: bin/hubot -a campfire --name rsc
```

**Logs:**

```
2016-12-17T11:20:53.198149+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-12-17T11:20:53.198657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to startin
g
2016-12-17T11:20:53.978046+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2016-12-17T11:20:54.099831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-12-17T11:20:54.832775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/hubot -a campfire --name rsc`
2016-12-17T11:21:00.807546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to u
p
2016-12-17T11:21:00.535290+00:00 app[web.1]: [Sat Dec 17 2016 11:21:00 GMT+0000
(UTC)] ERROR hubot-heroku-alive included, but missing HUBOT_HEROKU_KEEPALIVE_URL
. `heroku config:set HUBOT_HEROKU_KEEPALIVE_URL=$(heroku apps:info -s  | grep we
b-url | cut -d= -f2)`
2016-12-17T11:21:00.675448+00:00 app[web.1]: [Sat Dec 17 2016 11:21:00 GMT+0000
(UTC)] INFO hubot-redis-brain: Discovered redis from REDISCLOUD_URL environment
variable
2016-12-17T11:21:00.768728+00:00 app[web.1]: [Sat Dec 17 2016 11:21:00 GMT+0000
(UTC)] INFO hubot-redis-brain: Successfully authenticated to Redis
2016-12-17T11:21:00.784649+00:00 app[web.1]: [Sat Dec 17 2016 11:21:00 GMT+0000
(UTC)] INFO hubot-redis-brain: Data for hubot brain retrieved from Redis
```

Now from where do I ping to hubot? From campfire website? I did but its not responding

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need two parameters in the route, and you have only one (res):

```
   robot.hear /room/i, (req, res) ->
     res.send "welcome " + res.message.room
```

Comment: But am I pinging from right place? From campfire chat room?